# How can I escape text for an XML document in Perl?

Tags: xml, perl, escaping

Anyone know of any Perl module to escape text in an XML document?

I'm generating XML which will contain text that was entered by the user. I want to correctly handle the text so that the resulting XML is well formed.

Comment: What kind of "escaping" are you referring to?

Comment: Are you trying to create XML output by hand?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I personally prefer [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/) - Perl binding for libxml. One of the pros - it uses one of the fastest XML processing library available. Here is an example for creating text node:

```
use XML::LibXML;
my $doc = XML::LibXML::Document->new('1.0',$some_encoding);
my $element = $doc->createElement($name);
$element->appendText($text);
$xml_fragment = $element->toString();
$xml_document = $doc->toString();
```

And, never, ever create XML by hand. It's gonna be bad for your health when people find out what you did.

Comment: Point taken. I shouldn't have created the XML by hand (they were simple XML documents when I started). I'll need to get around to rewriting those bits of code.

Comment: I've accepted this answer not for the XML::LibXML recommendation (I used XML::Writer) but for pointing out that it is not good practice to create XML by hand.

Comment: Note that XML::LibXML has non-perl dependencies and might not readily install on your platform.

Comment: you're missing `$doc->setDocumentElement($element);` if you want to get everything in

Answer (score 11):

The XML::Simple escape_value could be used also, but use of XML::Simple is not recommended for new programs.  See this post post 17436965.

A manual escape could be done using regex (copied from escape_value):

```
$data =~ s/&/&amp;/sg;
$data =~ s/</&lt;/sg;
$data =~ s/>/&gt;/sg;
$data =~ s/"/&quot;/sg;
```

Comment: this naive implementation usually works, but for cases `a.txt = " a&b "` this wont work.

Comment: @zinking It seems to work fine for me using the string you provided.

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure why you need to escape text that is in an XML file. If your file contains:

```
<foo>x < y</foo>
```

The file is **not** an XML file despite the proliferation of angle brackets. An XML file must contain valid data meaning something like this:

```
<foo>x &lt; y</foo>
```

or

```
<foo><![CDATA[x < y]]></foo>
```

Therefore, either:

1. You are not asking for escaping data in an XML file. Rather, you want to figure out how to put character data in an XML file so the resulting file is valid XML; or
2. You have some data in an XML file that needs to be escaped for *some other reason*.

Care to elaborate?

Comment: People get mad when you remind them that their pseudo-XML is not actually real XML.  It is amusing... and sad.  Anyway, I upvoted you :)

Comment: My question would be #1. I didn't realise my question wasn't clear. I'll update the question to clarify.

Comment: here my case is I am putting one XML inside another SOAP, and the soap parser have problem parsing the encapsulated message.

Comment: Useless non-answer. Yes, the original question was not very clear, but it was still easy to guess, or you could have asked for clarification. I understnad your point, but it would come across better if it were with a useful answer (like most other answers on this page).

Answer (score 6):

Use [XML::Code](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::Code).

From CPAN

XML::code escape()

Normally any content of the node will be escaped during rendering (i. e. special symbols like '&' will be replaced by corresponding entities). Call escape() with zero argument to prevent it:

```
        my $p = XML::Code->('p');
        $p->set_text ("&#8212;");
        $p->escape (0);
        print $p->code(); # prints <p>&#8212;</p>
        $p->escape (1);
        print $p->code(); # prints <p>&amp;#8212;</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

[XML::Entities](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::Entities):

```
use XML::Entities;
my $a_encoded = XML::Entities::numify('all', $a);
```

Edit: XML::Entities only numifies HTML entities. Use [HTML::Entities](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML::Entities) encode_entities($a) instead

Comment: XML::Entities::numify seems only to convert named XML entities to numeric XML entities.

Comment: You are right, my mistake. It is possible to use HTML::Entities and encode_entities instead.

Answer (score 3):

Use

XML::Generator

> require XML::Generator;
>
> my $xml = XML::Generator->new( ':pretty', escape => 'always,apos' );
>
> print $xml->h1( " &<   >non-html plain text<  >&" );

which will print all content inside the tags escaped (no conflicts with the markup).

Comment: Nice interface but too slow if you are writing millions of lines of XML.

Answer (score 1):

After checking out XML::Code as recommended by Krish I found that this can be done using the XML::Code `text()` function. E.g.,

```
use XML::Code;
my $text = new XML::Code('=');
$text->set_text(q{> & < " ' "});
print $text->code(); # prints &gt; &lt; &amp; " ' "
```

Passing '=' creates a text node which when printed doesn't contain tags.
*Note:* this only works for text data. It wont correctly escape attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Although you better use a module like `XML::LibXML` or `XML::Code` you could wrap textual data in a CDATA section. You must only take care not to put `]]>` in it (this sequence is also disallowed *outside of* CDATA sections!):

```
$text =~ s/\]\]>/]]>]]&gt;<![CDATA[/;
$text = "<![CDATA[$text]]>";
$xml = "<foo>$text</foo>";
```

As bonus your code will look more perlish obfuscated! :-)

Answer (score 0):

For programs that need to handle every special case, by all means use an official library for this task. However, [theoretically there are only 5 characters that need escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1091953/430128) in XML.

So, for one-offs that you don't want to pull in an extra library for, the following perl expression should suffice:

```perl
perl -pe 's/\&/\&amp;/g; s/</\&lt;/g; s/>/\&gt;/g; s/"/\&quot;/g; s/'"'"'/\&apos;/g'
```