# Safely generating XML in Lua

Tags: xml, lua, rss, atom-feed

I'm writing a Lua application that generates an Atom feed. Right now, I'm generating XML "by hand" -- writing strings to files.

This doesn't seem like the best way, although it may be. I am getting nervous about having the escaping exactly right. Has anyone done anything like this in Lua before?

Should I stick with generating "by hand"? Or write a wrapper for an existing C library?

(Perl, by comparison, seems to have [a plethora of options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137790/how-can-i-escape-text-for-an-xml-document-in-perl).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've now got one more answer to my question: I've written Lua bindings for [Tim Bray's C XML generator, Genx](http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/200x/2004/02/20/GenxStatus).

Here's its [homepage](http://genx.luaforge.net/); here's the [project on Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org/adrian/lgenx/). It's an incomplete binding right now, but it works for simple tasks:

```
require 'genx'
d = genx.new(io.stdout)

d:startElement('farm')

d:startElement('crop')
d:attribute('type', 'fruit')
d:text('Apricots')
d:endElement()

d:startElement('crop')
d:attribute('type', 'vegetable')
d:text('Zucchini')
d:endElement()

d:endElement()
```

Produces:

```
<farm><crop type="fruit">Apricots</crop><crop type="vegetable">Zucchini</crop></farm>
```

Personally, I find this kind of "streaming" interface slightly nicer to work with than a tree-based interface for generation.

Answer (score 2):

I've generated XML by hand too.  I created an API that looks like:

```
function XmlElement(tag, text, attr)
    ...
end

function XmlSubelement(root, tag, text, attr)
    ...
end
```

Then to use it:

```
local root = XmlElement("Level0")
XmlSubelement(root, "Level1", "some text")
XmlSubelement(root, "Level1", "some more text")

local s = root:tostring()
```

I don't have the code any longer, but it fit on one screen including the quoting.

Comment: Thanks; that's a good suggestion. I may end up going this route or just writing a binding to a C library like GenX.

Answer (score 1):

There are various data persistence libraries for Lua as well, many are described at the [Lua user's wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/). The [page on XML](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaXml) has information that could help.

<strike>The nice folks over at the [Kepler project](https://www.keplerproject.org/) have generators for HTML which can be used for generating valid XML.</strike> (Dead link.)

There is also [cosmo](http://cosmo.luaforge.net/) which is a generalized template framework that can be used to generate XML (among other things).

**Edit:**

I understand the concern for templates not necessarily providing guarantees that the output remains well formed. I'm pretty sure that the authors of Cosmo would be unhappy if a well-formed template ever produced a mal-formed document, but there is still the issue of properly quoting the content. In the contexts where I've used it, this hasn't been an issue for me, but I also haven't been working from untrusted source text.

There are also projects posted at LuaForge that may be useful:

- [Lua Element Tree](http://luaforge.net/projects/etree/) maps an XML document to and from a tree of tables. It uses Expat for reading, and claims to generate valid XML when writing.
- [LuaSOAP](http://luaforge.net/projects/luasoap/) Includes XML generation and parsing sufficient for SOAP transactions. If you decide to write your own generator, this might be a good starting point for a limited dialect such as RSS or ATOM.

Also, I know I've seen a project that implemented a complete DOM for HTML documents and supported both parsing and document generation, but I can't remember its name or locate it today at LuaForge.

**Edit 2:** Here's another package that I hadn't noticed before, even though it is included in [Lua for Windows](http://luaforwindows.luaforge.net/): [LuaXML](http://www.viremo.de/LuaXML/). It maps between XML and nest of Lua tables, and can both read and write XML.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, templating systems (like Cosmo) aren't any safer or easier than generating by hand -- I'd like something that might help me generate well-formed XML. Something that can guarantee well-formedness would be even better. I also don't see any XML generation libraries on lua-users.org or as part of Kepler -- luaexpat (http://www.keplerproject.org/luaexpat/) is just for parsing and the libxml2 bindings seem to have vanished.

Comment: I added a couple of links to LuaForge projects that also approach your needs. I haven't spotted a perfect solution, however.

Comment: Thanks for the specifics! I'll definitely investigate both of these.